# Angular 4 Template-Forms multi-field validation directive and ngModelGroup

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to validate a typical `new password` and `confirm password` match using an `Angular Directive`. The error message is not shown even though the directive correctly catches a mis-match:

**Template Form**

```
 <form>
    <md-input-container class="signup-full-width">
      <input 
        mdInput 
        autocomplete="off" 
        type="password"
        name="password"
        #currentPasswd="ngModel" 
        placeholder="Current password" 
        [(ngModel)]="currentPassword"            
        required>
        <md-error *ngIf="currentPasswd.errors && (currentPasswd.dirty || currentPasswd.touched)" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> 
          <div [hidden]="!currentPasswd.errors.required">Required</div>
        </md-error>                      
    </md-input-container>

     <div ngModelGroup="passwordGroup" password-matcher #passwordGroup="ngModelGroup"> 
      <md-input-container class="signup-full-width">
        <input 
          mdInput 
          autocomplete="off"
          type="password"                
          name="newPassword"
          #newPasswd="ngModel" 
          placeholder="New password" 
          [(ngModel)]="newPassword" 
          required
          minlength="8"
          maxlength="15">
        <md-error *ngIf="newPasswd.errors && (newPasswd.dirty || newPasswd.touched)" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> 
          <div [hidden]="!newPasswd.errors.required">Required</div>
          <div [hidden]="!newPasswd.errors.minlength">Must be at least 8 characters</div>
          <div [hidden]="!newPasswd.errors.maxlength">Must be at most 15 characters</div>
        </md-error>                      
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="signup-full-width">
        <input 
          mdInput    
          autocomplete="off"
          type="password"            
          name="confirmPassword" 
          placeholder="Confirm password" 
          [(ngModel)]="confirmPassword">
         <md-error *ngIf="passwordGroup.control?.errors" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}">  
          <div [hidden]="!passwordGroup.control.errors.noMatch">Passwords do not match</div>
         </md-error>             
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <p>passwordGroup.control?.errors: {{passwordGroup.control?.errors | json}}</p>

  </form>
```

Please note the `ngModelGroup` on the `div` surrounding 'new password' and 'confirm passords' fields.

**The password directive** 
[Angular 2 Forms | Kara Erickson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4)

```
function passwordMatcher(c: AbstractControl) {
  if (!c.get("newPassword") || !c.get("confirmPassword")) return null;

  return c.get("newPassword").value === c.get("confirmPassword").value
    ? null : {"noMatch": true};
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[password-matcher]',
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, multi: true, useValue: passwordMatcher}
  ]
})
export class PasswordMatcher {
}
```

However, the desired error message is never shown on 'Confirm Password' Input. Even though the directive appears to be working as evident from the debug output:

[image]

Comment: are you using the code from : https://github.com/kara/ac-forms ? Or have you typed your own code in?

Comment: @JGFMK, My own code

Comment: Probably just as well. I tried downloading and npm installing off that project.. Lots of out of date stuff. So not straight forward to try and do ng serve. Shame author didn't post an updated package.json.

Comment: Have you tried uploading your project into Plunker? If you did you could post a link that people could run. You need a github account to do that,,,

Comment: I need 'required' on the confirm-password, this kicks error message logic somehow.

Comment: I'd be wanting to debug it in Chrome console to get clearer understanding of how to answer your question. This is why I think Plunker will get you your answer from someone.

Comment: Good idea, will create a Plunker.

Comment: You did register PassWordMatcher in app-module.ts, in the @ ngModule, declarations: [] array right? and import the constant NG_VALIDATORS per @ 17:30 .. 18:14  in video? https://youtu.be/xYv9lsrV0s4?t=1050

Comment: Here's her slide link too: http://g.co/ng/ac16-forms

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
<input #newPasswd="ngModel" ... [(ngModel)]="newPassword" >
```

I noticed  @18:13 in Kara's video it looked like this:
`<input ngModel name="password" ... #password="ngModel"`>

Try changing your code in both places to this syntax/sequence see if that fixes it.

**Hint**: It's because newPasswd is what directive would need surely with your syntax.
You are using newPassword from name, not the # Angular template variable.