# Form validation Angular 4 | multi-field validation | Set error on empty Field depending on other field

Tags: typescript, angular4-forms

I have a form where two fields ('*From date*' and '*To Date*') are there along with other fields.
Requirement:

1. User can provide only '*From Date*'
2. If both date are given '*From date*' must NOT be greater than '*To Date*'; if given '*To Date*' will be underlined with Red.
3. If one provides '*To Date*' only, then the '*From Date*' will be underlined with Red.

To do this I used a frombuilder 'SrchForm' like this:

```
myForm(){
    this.srchGrp = this.SrchForm.group({
       //other FormcontrolNames
       from_date : '',     // from_date controlname for 'From Date' field
       to_date : '',       // to_date controlname for 'To Date' field
    }, {validator:  this.fromNtoValidate('from_date', 'to_date')})
 }
```

And,

```
fromNtoValidate(from_date, to_date){
    return (group: FormGroup)=>{
        let fromdate = group.controls['from_date'],
        let todate = group.controls['to_date'],

        if(formdate.value && todate.value){          // if both date provided
          if (formdate.value > todate.value){
             return todate.setErrors({'incorrect' : true});
          }
        }

       if(!formdate.value && todate.value){          // **if Todate provided only
            console.log("only Todate Given"); 
            return fromdate.setErrors({'incorrect' : true});
       } 
   }
}
```

`**if Todate provided only` part is failing to red-mark the `Form Date` field though it's printing `only Todate Given` as expected. If I try to set error on  `todate` instead of 'fromdate', then it's working fine but not working on `fromdate`.

Please suggest me what to do here and mark where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This can help you a little.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262323/angular-4-template-forms-multi-field-validation-directive-and-ngmodelgroup

Comment: It's not working.